# Не получается скомпилировать данный код для шифратора - дешифратора

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Много ошибок по коду ничего не понимаю (

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static SecretKeySpec secret;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public static SecretKey generateKey()
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
    {
        String password = null;
        return secret = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(), "AES");
    }


    public static byte[] encryptMsg(String message, SecretKey secret)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidParameterSpecException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static String decryptMsg(byte[] cipherText, SecretKey secret)
            throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidParameterSpecException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);
        String decryptString = new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), "UTF-8");
        return decryptString;
    }
    
    
    public void Encrypt (View view) //Зашифровать
    {
        EditText el1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText el2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        SecretKey secret = generateKey();
        EncUtil.encryptMsg(String toEncrypt, secret))

    }

    public void Decrypt (View view) //Расшифровать
    {
        EditText el1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText el2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        EncUtil.decryptMsg(byte[] toDecrypt, secret))

    }
}
```

////

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Слово обычное"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColorHint="#000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Encrypt"
        android:text="Зашифровать" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="#000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Слово шифрованное"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Decrypt"
        android:text="Расшифровать" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Было бы в крайней степени полезно увидеть это множество ошибок. Это помогло бы конкретизировать вопрос, потому что сейчас он не соответствует [требованиям хорошего вопроса (слишком общий)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Answer (score 0):

На будущее - не вставляйте код скриншотами, это чертовски неудобно. Вот я хочу процитировать ваш код, чтобы указать в нем проблему, а не могу

У вас есть метод `Encrypt`, который не бросает исключений. И есть метод `generateKey()`, вызываемый в `Encrypt`, который может бросит исключения. Обработки этих исключений в `Encrypt` у вас нет. То то есть если в `generateKey` что-то пойдет не так эту ошибку обработать будет некому. Либо засуньте вызов generateKey в `try/catch`, который ловит нужные типы исключений, либо поставьте для метода `Encrypt` возможность выбрасывать исключения тех типов, которые выбрасывает `generateKey`. Тогда `try/catch` нужно ставить там, где вызывается `Encrypt`